# Visa: travelling from Italy to Cuba through Russia

Tags: visas, transit-visas, russia, cuba, italian-citizens

I'm going to Cuba this summer and was wondering which visa I need, based on the fact that my flight could stop in Moscow ( Russia ) and then fly to Cuba from there. I'm in Italy.
Do I need 2 visa? One for Cuba and one for Russia? Do I need any other documents? Where should I get those documents?
I'm Italian.